# How do I check if pressed on a text in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

How do I check if pressed on a text?

This is how I draw the text:

```
# Full code on https://github.com/Zwengel/bunny-badgers
height = pygame.display.Info().current_h
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 24)
spText = "Single Player"
sp = font.render(spText, True, (0,0,0))
spRect = sp.get_rect()
spRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
spRect.centery = height/12*5
screen.blit(sp, spRect)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about pygame but normally you would get click coordinates and check if they are inside text bounding box.

Comment: @nikoliazekter Yeah, I can get the mouse position with `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and store it to a list called mpos with `mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pygame.Rect.collidepoint() to get that the text was clicked on.
The documentation on the function is [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint).

Here is an example of how you can use the function to your desired effect:

```
mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() # Get mouse position
if spRect.collidepoint(mpos): # Check if position is in the rect
    # Code for what you wish the click to do
```

This code will check if you clicked on the desired rect object, and execute whatever code your heart desires.

I hope this helps. (: